# ANTLR4 Listeners: Should I override EnterXXX or ExitXXX?

Tags: compilation, antlr4

When I implement a parse tree listener for doing things like building symbol tables, it seems to me that I can override either the EnterXXX or ExitXXX methods for things like function and variable declarations.  As far as I can tell, it should not make a difference which one I override. Is there a best practice here, or some compelling reason to override one versus the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some algorithms, only one of the two is correct. If that's not the case for your algorithm, then you're only bound by a "rule" of being consistent. :)